# PHP mail function only send spam

Tags: php, function, email, spam

I have a question about the PHP mail function. While I'm using it only sends emails which are detected as Spam, and changing or adding headers doesn't make any difference.

Here is my code:

```
            $to      = $email;
            $subject = "The Subject";
            $message = "This is a message<br/>
                        This is another line<br>
                        And another line..<br>";
            $headers = "From: example@mydomain.com\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: example@mydomain.com\r\n";
            $headers .= "Return-Path: example@mydomain.com\r\n";

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: would be better if you use Php-Mailer atleast.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Use $headers = "From: noreply@mydomain.com \r\n";
  instead of
$headers = "From: example@mydomain.com\r\n";
                          OR 
   Use the following: its working fine for me:
    $touser=$email;
    $subjectAdmin= "demo";
    $headersAdmin = "From: noreply@demo.com\r\n"; 
    $headersAdmin .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $messageuser ='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01  
    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
    <html lang="en"> 
    <head>
    <title>demo</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
    <div style="margin:0 auto;">
    <p>message</p>
    <div style="clear:both;font-size:14px; text-align:left; width:100%;"> 
    <br/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>'; 
     $emailSenduser = mail($touser,$subjectAdmin,$messageuser,$headersAdmin);
```